# Helix with mixed handedness

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, research

I'm currently interested in the mathematics and the mechanism of chirality inversion that could take place in (regular/irregular) helices, for which it possesses both left- and right-handed sections. A common example for this would be the [tendril perversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendril_perversion) found in Nature.

There are several papers on this by physicists: to identify it from the Darboux vector [Silva et. al. (2016)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep23413?trendmd-shared=0), or as soliton-like objects [Nisoli & Balatsky (2015)](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.91.062601) and [Sun & Mao (2021)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.098001)). This mixed handedness is also relatively common to be found in various nucleic acids, hence numerous papers by chemists and biologists.

I'd really appreciate any resources (textbooks, papers, etc.) on this done purely from mathematics point of view.

Comment: Welcome to (posting at) Math.SE! <> Just an elementary comment that a tendril can be modeled as a graph $\theta = f(x)$ wrapped around a (unit, say) cylinder): $F(x) = (\cos f(x), \sin f(x), x)$. A perversion arises from a local extremum of $f$. This naturally ignores all the interesting physics (etc.) causing such structures to exist in nature.... <> It might be worth adding the "curves" tag (and any others on "differential topology" or "knots", and removing "general-topology").